# Proof concerning minimal sum for two factors of a number

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

I would like to know if this proof is correct and sufficiently thorough. It satisfies all of my concerns, and I thought this to be an intuitive fact. I am uncertain if it is intuitive enough to assume without context or proof. I have therefore made this somewhat concise proof.

(Context: I'm using this statement in a non-rigorous context discussing esoteric programming languages and proving optimally-short constructs.)

---

**Statement:** For a number $N$, the two factors $(a, b)$ of $N$, such that $a + b$ is minimal, are those that are closest to $\sqrt{N}$.

**Proof:** Consider the set of all unique unordered divisor pairs $(a, b)$ such that $ab = N$. It must be the case that the pair $(1, N)$ has the highest sum at $1 + N$. WLOG, say $(2, N/2)$ is also a divisor pair. This has the next highest sum, at $2 + N/2$. In general, each pair $(k, N/k)$ has a sum $k + N/k$, and that $k \le \sqrt{N}$. It should follow that by ordering the set of divisor pairs by the first element in ascending order, the sums are ordered by descending order. Then, the "final" pair in this list would be the ones closest to $\sqrt{N}$; thus, $a$ is the largest factor of $N$ such that $a \le \sqrt{N}$ and $a + b$ is minimized.

Comment: The statement is not true.  The two factors so that $a+b$ is minimal are $a =1$ and $b=$ the smallest prime factor.  Example: if $N = 1024$ than $a=1, b=2$ and $a+b=3$ is minimal.  I think what you actually meant so so was for a number $N$ and two complimentary factors, $(a,b)$ so that $N= a*b$ those that have the minimal $a+b$ will be those that are closest to $\sqrt{n}$.  That is indeed true.

Comment: " It must be the case that the pair (1,N) has the highest sum at 1+N"  Why is that the highest pair? "WLOG, say (2,N/2) is also a divisor pair."  In what sense is this WLOG?  This sees *very* specific and thus with an extreme hemoraging of loss of generality.  "This has the next highest sum, at 2+N/2."  Why is that the next highest pair?  "It should follow that by ordering the set of divisor pairs by the first element in ascending order, the sums are ordered by descending order."  Why??? Why on earth do you think such a thing  I don't see that you have proven anything.  You've just assumed it.

Comment: @fleablood not prime factors, a divisor factor

Comment: @fleablood Sorry that my thoughts aren't perfect, it seems you think they should be.

Comment: I don't think your thoughts should be perfect.  But statements made should be verified.  Why is $1 + N > 2 + \frac N2$?  And why should $k + N > (k+1) + \frac N{k+1}$?  If you can answer why you think that would be true then you are well on the way to solving.  But you can't just claim them without reason.

Comment: @fleablood : I asked this question because I wasn't sure what I was assuming unduly. By your comment, I've gathered that I am thinking ridiculously and idiotically. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but that's how I perceive it.

Comment: It's not idiotic nor ridiculous.  But you are making assumptions that must be verified.  Why is $1 + N > 2 + \frac N2 > 3 + \frac N3 .... $etc.  Note. if this is true for non-integers it will also be true for integer factors.  If you can prove that $a < b \le \sqrt N \iff a + \frac Na > b + \frac Nb \ge 2\sqrt N$ you are done.  Maybe that reminds you of something.  Maybe the AM-GM theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can assume without loss of generality that your number is even. You also assert that various sums are ordered without giving any detailed check that this is the case.

However, given that $ab$ is fixed and you want to minimise $a+b$ you could note that $$(a+b)^2=4ab+(a-b)^2$$ and since the first term on the right is fixed, the square of the sum is smallest when $(a-b)^2$ is smallest i.e. when $a$ and $b$ are closest together.

Comment: I was mostly wanting "WLOG" to be "the next smallest factor" of N, not that it was even. My wording was not the best there, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

" It must be the case that the pair (1,N) has the highest sum at 1+N."

Why on earth would we assume that?

"It should follow that by ordering the set of divisor pairs by the first element in ascending order, the sums are ordered by descending order."

Why on earth would we assume that?

It seems to me those assumptions are precisely what needs to be proven.

The way I see it, you need to prove two things.

1) If $a*b = N$  and $a \le b$ then $1 \le a \le \sqrt N \le b \le N$

pf:  This is pretty obvious: If $a > \sqrt N$ then $a*b = N\implies b=\frac Na < \frac N{\sqrt N} = \sqrt N < a$ which is a contradiction.  So $a \le \sqrt N$ and $b = \frac Na \ge \frac N{\sqrt N} = \sqrt N$.

And obvious $1 \le a$ so $b = \frac Na \le N$.

2) If $a < c \le \sqrt N$ and $b = \frac Na; d=\frac Nc$ then $a + b > c + d$.

Pf:  Let $e = c - a$

Note:  $b -d = \frac Na - \frac N{a+e} = N\frac {(a+e) - a)}{a(a+e)}= e\frac N{ac}$

$c \le \sqrt N$ and $a < \sqrt N$ so $\frac N{ac} > \frac N{\sqrt N\sqrt N} = 1$.

So $b-d > e$.

So $a + b = (a +e) + (b-e) = c + (b-e) > c + d$